# How to declare Windows path in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to burn a blob column from an image that is saved in windows.
How do I declare the image path in Oracle PLSQL?

Ex:

```
DECLARE
  dest_lob BLOB;

  -- this line report ORA22285 "non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
  src_lob  BFILE := BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'C:\Users\gus\Desktop\image.jpg');

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO teste_gustavo_blob VALUES(2, EMPTY_BLOB())
    RETURNING imagem INTO dest_lob;

  DBMS_LOB.OPEN(src_lob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READONLY);
  DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile( DEST_LOB => dest_lob,
                     SRC_LOB  => src_lob,
                     AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(src_lob) );
  DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(src_lob);

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Note: I'm trying to insert a record into a table through a Windows machine using SQLDeveloper. The database is on a remote server.

Comment: Is the database running on your local machine?  Or on a server?  When you say "burn a blob" do you mean "load a blob"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database can only see directories which are local to it. It cannot see files on your PC (unless the database is running on that PC). So you cannot load your file through PL/SQL.

However, you say you are using SQL Developer. You can load a BLOB by editing the table's data in the Table Navigator. Click on the `Data` tab then edit the cell (the BLOB column of the row you want to load the file into). Use the Local Data > Load option to upload your file. That Jeff Smith has publish [a detailed step-by-step guide on his blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/).

Answer (score 2):

the path needs to be part of the directory object definition, and the file name is just that - just the file name.  Example;

```
CREATE DIRECTORY MY_DIR AS 'C:\Users\gus\Desktop';
..
   BFILENAME('MY_DIR', 'image.jpg');
```

Note that the directory is created on the **server** not your local machine.  So if you are trying to create a file on a local machine, this will not work in pl/sql.  PL/sql runs on the server, not the client.  In that case, you need to code a client.

Comment: The error persists. 
Error Reporting -
ORA-22288: File or LOBFILEOPEN operation failed
No such file or directory
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1014
ORA-06512: in line 8
22288. 00000 - "file or LOB operation% s failed \ n% s"
* Cause: The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
* Action: See the next error message in the error stack for more detailed
           information. Also, verify that the file or LOB exists and that
           the necessary privileges are set for the specified operation. If
           the error still persists, report the error to the DBA.

Comment: So you are running the database server on your windows machine then?

Comment: No, I'm trying to insert a record into a table through a Windows machine using SQLDeveloper

Comment: You can't do that.  The file has to exist on the server.  From oracle docs - "A directory object specifies an alias for a directory on the server file system where external binary file LOBs (BFILEs) and external table data are located. "

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. I needed to dev test a feature and I needed a PDF file in my DB. I read few questions here and formulated an answer. I inserted a row manually with SQL and changed the file manually after that.
The SQL:

```
insert into ATTACHMENT_TABLE (id, file_content) values 
(1, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('some dummy text'));
```

Using DBeaver, I edited the row and loaded the file from my windows PC. The end result is a row which contains the PDF file I wanted.